# Platform-specific git configuration files

Tags: git, git-config

I have three git configuration files. One is named `.gitconfig` and contains 90% of my git settings. Common, platform-agnostic settings go here. The other is named `.gitconfig-windows` and contains Windows-only settings for Git (Notepad++ as my editor, for example, which won't exist on Linux). I also have a `.gitconfig-linux` for the Linux platform, obviously.

Right now I have the following at the top of my `.gitconfig` file:

```
[include]
    path = .gitconfig-windows
```

Since I'm currently working out of windows, this means my `.gitconfig` will include all of the settings from `.gitconfig-windows`. When I'm on Linux, I have to edit my `.gitconfig` file to point to the `.gitconfig-linux` file instead. It's pretty tedious to have to edit my `.gitconfig` each time I switch platforms. I have all 3 of my config files in Dropbox for easy syncing between all of my work machines (mixture of Windows and Ubuntu environments). Any recommendations on how to more easily setup Git to use platform-specific settings on only those platforms?

Comment: This question might be too broad, I don't know. Anyways, I was thinking that you could simply set up symlinks in your home directory that point to your Dropbox files, then have your `include.path` point to each symlink. I'm not sure what will happen when Git finds non-existent files at a path though. Also, although Windows has an implementation of symlinks (especially Windows 7 and 8), I'm not sure if they'll work for this, although the Linux-style symlinks should definitely work.

Comment: Why don't you keep the files in a git repository with 3 branches: **master** having only the common `.gitconfig` file, **linux** having `.gitconfig` with the proper include and `.gitconfig-linux` and **windows** having `.gitconfig` with the proper include and `.gitconfig-windows`. And of course when you need to update the common settings file, you merge those changes in the platform specific branches.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I think that might result in time travel.

Comment: @RobertDailey, how come? Are you referring to the chicken the egg problem? If so, store them in a Mercurial repository :-D

Comment: @CristianCiupitu It sounds like a lot more trouble to keep all three branches up-to-date with each other than to just edit the file when changing platforms. The symlink idea sounds pretty good and I have no doubt it'll work for Windows - I did the same thing to move Minecraft saves around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rename your current `.gitconfig` file to something like `.gitconfig-common`, and change the platform-specific files to include it (instead of the other way around).  Then, on each machine where you work, create a `.gitconfig` file *outside* of Dropbox that does nothing but include the appropriate platform-specific file in your Dropbox.

So on Windows, for example, you'd have `.gitconfig` include `.gitconfig-windows`, which includes `.gitconfig-common`.  The `.gitconfig` file contains nothing but a platform-specific include directive so there's no need to synchronize it with Dropbox.

Comment: What's funny is I was actually doing exactly this for a while, but reversed them because many tools do not know how to read "includes" in git config files. So, it thought my .gitconfig was virtually empty and would give me a ton of warnings (GitExtensions is especially bad about this).